# One or more reference to type UIKit.UIWebView

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We are aware that in Xamarin.iOS, UIWebView will soon be deprecated and apps will not be accepted with deprecated versions.

I have created a new project [here](https://github.com/devWaleed/UIWebView-Fixed.git). I have followed this [document here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/) as well as other posts on internet to remove UIWebkit and replace it with WKWebview but it doesnt work.

Since its a new project, so no nuget packages are being used which could have had UIWebView. But still when i add --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView flag in mtouch arguments I get error:

> One or more reference(s) to type 'UIKit.UIWebView' already exists
>   inside 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' before linking   WebViewTest.iOS

How do I remove UIWebview complete from the basic project so my app can get accepted on testflight/appstore.

I am using Visual Studio 16.5.5 with Xamarin.iOS version 13.16 and I have tested on Xamarin forms 4.4 and 4.6 both

Comment: this process is pretty thoroughly documented - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Comment: @Jason I have followed that guide. The only thing that is different is that i am on debug mode and that documentation is for release mode. Do you think it will cause issues?

Comment: @Jason just tested on release mode, same error

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if it's Debug or Release. You need at least Forms 4.5 and you need to set the argument, like it states in the article.

Comment: @MihailDuchev please check my project, i have added those arguments already and tested on release as well. Those other arguments are just for showing warnings as i understood and should not interfere with linker

Comment: Have you tried uploading the ipa file to TestFlight? Does it get rejected? Or do you watch only the warning?

Comment: @MihailDuchev I followed microsoft's guide with ad hoc mode and upload on testflight, it gave me error. I have not uploaded on testflight with release mode so far.

Comment: Try and share the results.

Answer (score 0):

In project file [WebViewTest.iOS.csproj](https://github.com/devWaleed/UIWebView-Fixed/blob/master/WebViewTest/WebViewTest.iOS/WebViewTest.iOS.csproj) remove `--warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView -warnaserror:1502 -warnaserror:1503`

It should look like this

```xml
<MtouchExtraArgs>--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type</MtouchExtraArgs>
```

Use latest Visual Studio for Mac

also set **Linker behavior** to *SDK framework only* or *All* - this is important